# Adding splash screen image shows error in meteor app

Tags: cordova, meteor, launch-screen

I am trying to add splash screen to my meteor app. In `mobile-config.js` file after adding

```
App.launchScreens({
    //iOS
    'iphone_2x': '/images/splash/splash-375x667@2x.png'    
});
```

when I run `meteor run ios-device`, it shows the following error:

> Error while running for mobile platforms: ENOENT, stat
>   '/images/splash/splash-375x667@2x.png'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the formatting. I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file path(s) should probably not start with a slash. For a splash image located in `yourApp/images/splash/splash-375x667@2x.png`:

```
App.launchScreens({
    //iOS
    'iphone_2x': 'images/splash/splash-375x667@2x.png'    
});
```

See [the official localmarket example's config](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/localmarket/mobile-config.js) from MDG's github for reference.

Comment: Thank you. It works. It was the path problem. It should be 'public/mages/splash/splash-375x667@2x.png'